# ADO.NET Parameter causes a timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a big nasty pivot query that I run from C# via ADO.NET. I use this in 2 places and in 1 place I want the data but in the other place I just want the structure (no data). So in the query I added in the where clause:

`1 = @test`

So in the query where I only want the table structure I set `@test` to 2 and that works great. However, in the query I want the data I set it to 1 but that query times out then (after 5 mins). If I pull the sql into sql server and manually set the parameter it comes back in 3 mins. If I remove the `1 = @test` completely from my C# app it comes back in 3 mins just fine. If I hardcode `1 = 1` in my C# app it comes back in 3 mins just fine.

I'm also adding a date parameter in this query and that works just fine.

**My question is, what in the world about the @test parameter could cause this timeout from happening?**

Is there a way to see what ADO.NET is really sending over to SQL Server for my query?

Comment: sql server default timeout is less than 3 minutes i guess and that's the reason it is timing, consider optimizing your query, 3 minutes is too much time

Comment: An SP and unexpected timeout duration may be [*Parameter Sniffing*](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx)

Comment: Sql Server Profiler could show what the server receives.

Comment: My guess would a bad cached query plan.  You probably asked first where `@test` was 0, SQL server optimized the query, realized that there was no data going to be returned and then used a simple query plan for it.  Then when you asked again with `@test` = 1, it used the same plan which was terrible when it actually had to return data.

Comment: @Ehsan I'm setting the timeout to 5 manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is to modify the actual query when you need to do a structure only so that it contains your 1=@test. That way two separate query plans will be created, one for each type of query, both of which will be optimized best for the query it actually needs to do.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like that's the workaround. It's just sucks duplicating basically the entire query just for this. Something that seems like SQL Server outsmarting itself.